# Speedups in Looping Structures

Tags: python, performance, list, python-2.7, python-3.x

I notice some interesting behavior when it comes to building lists in different ways. `.append` takes longer than list-comprehensions, which take longer than `map`, as shown in the experiments below:

```
def square(x): return x**2

def appendtime(times=10**6):
  answer = []
  start = time.clock()
  for i in range(times):
    answer.append(square(i))
  end = time.clock()
  return end-start

def comptime(times=10**6):
  start = time.clock()
  answer = [square(i) for i in range(times)]
  end = time.clock()
  return end-start

def maptime(times=10**6):
  start = time.clock()
  answer = map(square, range(times))
  end = time.clock()
  return end-start

for func in [appendtime, comptime, maptime]:
  print("%s: %s" %(func.__name__, func()))
```

Python 2.7:

```
appendtime: 0.42632
comptime: 0.312877
maptime: 0.232474
```

Python 3.3.3:

```
appendtime: 0.614167
comptime: 0.5506650000000001
maptime: 0.57115
```

Now, I am very aware that `range` in python 2.7 builds a list, so I get why there is a disparity between the times of the corresponding functions in python 2.7 and 3.3. What I am more concerned about is the relative time differences between `append`, list-comprehension and `map`.

At first, I considered that this might be because `map` and list comprehensions may afford the interpreter knowledge of the eventual size of the resultant list, which would allow the interpreter to malloc a sufficiently large C array under the hood to store the list. By that logic, list-comprehensions and `map` should take pretty much the same amount of time.
However, the timing data shows that in python 2.7, listcomps are ~1.36x as fast as `append`, and `map` is ~1.34x as fast as listcomps.
More curious is that in python 3.3, listcomps are ~1.12x as fast as `append`, and `map` is actually slower than listcomps.

Clearly, `map` and listcomps don't "play by the same rules"; clearly, map takes advantage of something that listcomps don't.
Could anybody shed some light on the reason behind the difference in these timing values?

Comment: Obligatory "Why didn't you use `timeit`? It's much better for benchmarking." comment.

Comment: @delnan -- I was thinking this one too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in python3.x, `map` returns an `iterable`, NOT a list, so that explains the 50kx speedup there.  To make it a fair timing, in python3.x you'd need `list(map(...))`.

Second, `.append` will be slower because each time through the loop, the interpretter needs to look up the list, then it needs  to look up the `append` function on the list.  This additional `.append` lookup does not need to happen with the list-comp or map.

Finally, with the list-comprehension, I believe the function `square` needs to be looked up at every turn of your loop.  With map, it is only looked up when you call map which is why if you're calling a function in your list-comprehension, `map` will typically be faster.  Note that a list-comprehension usually beats out `map` with a `lambda` function though.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget -- Yeah, I added more to try to explain that difference.

Comment: I've updated my post with `list(map(...))`, which seems slower. Could you please address that?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget -- Not sure that I can.  It might be because in this case, you actually need to call `map(...).__iter__`  and then the `__next__` function a whole bunch of times (which you're not doing with the list-comp).  In any event, your discrepancy is only ~5% which is pretty minimal.