# collecting values from objects in a list

Tags: python, lambda

I have a list consisting of objects of custom class, e.g.:

```
class myClass:
    pass

myList=[]

for i in range(100):
    myObj=myClass()
    myObj.prop1=i
    myObj.prop2=i*i
    myList.append(myObj)
```

now I want to collect all values of certain property of these objects to separate list; right now I do it this way:

```
myValuesList = []
for obj in myList: myValuesList.append(obj.prop1)
```

Is there better/faster way? Something to do with `map` and `lambda`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[List comprehensions tend to be faster](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20150935/198633):

```
myValueList = [obj.prop1 for obj in myList]
```

`operator.attrgetter` with `map` might be faster:

```
myValueList = map(operator.attrgetter('prop1'), myList)  # use list(map(...)) in python3.x
```

Comment: Similarly the first loop can be replaced with a LC too if OP can define a `__init__` method in `myClass`.

Comment: Thank you! However, second variant is not yet clear for me: when I run `myValueList = list(map(operator.attrgetter('prop1'), myList))` (I am on Python 3), I get an error `NameError: name 'operator' is not defined`

Comment: @VasilyA: `import operator`